# Qt: how to include path with space in pro

Tags: c++, path, escaping, special-characters, qt-creator

Platform: `Windows 10`

Qt Version: `5.15.1`

For example, I want to include this path `C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt` in the pro file.

**Here are the ways I've tried:**

1. use `$$quote()`:

   ```
   INCLUDEPATH += $$quote(C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt)
   ```
2. use `" "`:

   ```
   INCLUDEPATH += "C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt"
   ```
3. use `$$quote` and `" "` together:

   ```
   INCLUDEPATH += $$quote("C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt")
   ```
4. change `\\` to `/`:

   ```
   INCLUDEPATH += $$quote("C:/Program Files (x86)/Windows Kits/10/Include/10.0.18362.0/ucrt")
   ```

All no good, and this is the error I keep getting:

[image: Qt Creator error]

Answer (score 2):

You need to quote with `""` and use forward slashes without `$$quote`

> To specify a path containing spaces, quote the path using the technique described in Whitespace.
>
> ```
> win32:INCLUDEPATH += "C:/mylibs/extra headers"
> unix:INCLUDEPATH += "/home/user/extra headers"
> ```
>
> [INCLUDEPATH](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmake-variable-reference.html#includepath)

Comment: When changing INCLUDEPATH in the .PRO file, you need to Rebuild, not just Build.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
INCLUDEPATH += "C:\'Program Files (x86)'\WindowsKits\10\Include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt"
```

Comment: thanks, but still not working. I really don’t see any clues for this problem. :(

Answer (score 0):

I had success with `$$shell_quote`

as in:

```
$$shell_quote("C:\Program Files\Git\bin\bash.exe") make_version_header.sh
```

See the [Qt5 docs for `shell_quote`](http://web.archive.org/web/20210507040132/https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmake-function-reference.html).

Here it is in a working project (one on GitHub with passing CI jobs): https://github.com/219-design/qt-qml-project-template-with-ci/blob/22788b05738a/windows.pri#L33